# How to determine if application is running on X11 platform on Qt6?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt6

I am working to port a Qt5 application to Qt6. Since `Qt X11 Extras` module is removed in Qt6 and I have to check if the platform is `X11`, how do I do that?

This is what the current implementation is using.

```
 if (QX11Info::isPlatformX11())
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
```

I have other use cases of `QX11Info` class as well. How do I port this? I don't seem to find any other solution.

Comment: Possibly off topic but... can I ask why you need `QX11Info`?  What particular functionality do you use?

Comment: @G.M. The code uses it find ICC monitor profiles set on the system. The code uses specifically `QX11Info::display()`, `QX11Info::appScreen` `QX11Info::appRootWindow()`

Comment: It just uses `if(QGuiApplication::platformName() == QLatin1String("xcb")){}` which is literally what that function does in Qt5. https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtx11extras.git/tree/src/x11extras/qx11info_x11.cpp#n102

Answer (score 1):

QGuiApplication::platformName() check should be fine, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qguiapplication.html#platformName-prop

BTW, QX11Info and other things in QtX11Extras were moved into QtGui(dev branch, 6.2), see also https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/348530 .